# Regular Expression tool like SQLFiddle

Tags: web-apps, library, web-services, regex

SQLFiddle is a webservice where you can setup and work with small examples of SQL on various systems (PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc...)

I am looking for such a webservice or library that parses RegExes in various languages (Java, Perl, C#, etc...) and executes them against a given text.

[RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) is a good start but doesn't allow me to change the implementation.

*The idea is to suggest this library/webservice for [a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255405/improving-regexp-answers) on Stack Overflow.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/), I think it most closely matches what you are looking for.

RegexPlanet is an

> "Online Regular Expression (Regex) Testing and Cookbook for: Go,
>   Haskell, Java, JavaScript, .Net, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, Tcl &
>   XRegExp"

- It has support for 11 languages, including [Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), [Perl](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html), [.NET](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html) and [Ruby](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/ruby/index.html).
- It even has a shortcode feature for sharing regex snippets (e.g. http://fiddle.re/x9g86) and I've seen it used (and used it myself) in SO questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652973/javas-regex-confusion).

I've been using it for a while now, highly recommended.

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby:**
  http://rubular.com/

Rublar is a regular expression editor for Ruby that has inspired many others, and it may be a good search stub.

**JavaScript, Python, PCRE:**
https://www.debuggex.com/

Debuggex is fairly new, but it sports some pretty nice railroad diagrams for visualizing regular expressions.

Diagrams are especially nice for reading regular expression others have written, for example this (primitive) URL pattern [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128168/validation-for-url-domain-using-regex-rails) for validation:

```
^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

[image]

I use Rubular very frequently, for testing regular expression matches for everything from actual Ruby code to .htaccess files. Ruby, like most things I use, has PCRE regular expessions. So, no real need to use another tool.

I only use Debuggex when I am deciphering large regular expressions that I did not write.

Comment: Rubular isn't relevant here, being only about Ruby. Debuggex barely, with only three formats.

Comment: @Gilles, it absolutely is relevant as it has, as I stated, inspired many other editors, and is a good place to search from. For example http://alternativeto.net/software/rubular/. Also, Debuggex, has support for PCRE regular expressions used in Perl, PHP, Delphi, C, Apache, R, Nmap, Postfix, etc.

Comment: Moreover, the railroad diagrams on Debuggex are similar to those used in the book *Javascript: The Good Parts*, and are an excellent addition to the metastackoverflow question linked.

Comment: @kwarrick Did you use them? If so, what are your experiences? When do you use which?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I use Rubular very frequently, for testing regular expression matches for everything from actual Ruby code to .htaccess files. Ruby, like most things I use, has PCRE regular expessions. So, no real need to use another tool. I only use Debuggex when I am deciphering large regular expressions that I did not write.

Answer (score 0):

http://regex101.com/ fits your needs

```
regular expressions 101  — an online regex tester for javascript, php, pcre and python.
```

It is one of my favourite regex expression testers. It supports PCRE, Javascript and Python regular expressions. It also includes a powerful debugger and handy quick reference of regex syntax as well as code generation for popular programming languages, so you can copy and paste already escaped regex.

Answer (score 0):

https://regexr.com/

RegExr describes itself as an online tool to learn, build, & test Regular Expressions:

- Supports JavaScript & PHP/PCRE RegEx.
- Results update in real-time as you type.
- Roll over a match or expression for details.
- Validate patterns with suites of Tests.
- Save & share expressions with others.
- Use Tools to explore your results.
- Full RegEx Reference with help & examples.
- Undo & Redo with ctrl-Z / Y in editors.
- Search for & rate Community Patterns.

By the way, it is also open source:
https://github.com/gskinner/regexr/